# What is equivalent of coord_flip in ggplot2 for metricsgraphics?

Tags: r, widget, shiny

I am trying to flip my metricsgraphics chart (made in r for use in a shiny App, using the metricsgraphics html-widget).

I have been able to successfully show it in my ShinyApp, but would really like to apply the equivalent of

```
ggplot2::coord_flip()
```

but for the metricsgraphics

```
mjs_bar()
```

function.

Is this something that is possible? I have yet to find the option to do so in the MetricsGraphics.js documentation.

My code is the following:

```
        barchart %>%
            mjs_plot(x=year,y=population,
                    width = 300,
                    height = 400,
                    show_rollover_text = TRUE,
                    decimals = 2) %>%
                    mjs_bar() ->
```

})

```
output$mjs2 <- renderMetricsgraphics(m2)
```

The relevant packages are the follwing:

metricsgraphics_0.6.1 
htmlwidgets_0.3.2
htmltools_0.2.6

Thanks in advance